# Dynamic font size when there is change of culture (language)

Tags: c#, html, css, fonts

Having a mvc web application, with the css coded in stylesheet which will be used in views.

Is there any way to achieve the following scenario:

> When there is a change of language culture from english to other
>   language, the css for certain class font size will increase by 3px, but when the
>   language culture from other language back to english, the font size
>   will decrease back by 3px to the original size.

So far have been researching online, but could not find a clue to have the `font size` in css stylesheet to change via reading of `CurrentUICulture` of C# (or alternatively reading from cookie)

Comment: DO you mean the font size of every tag(h1-h6,p,li,div,span,a e.t.c) on the whole page?

Comment: nope, only certain class name is involve in changing language of the font, font that doesn't change language has no change of size

Comment: How about throwing on an extra class to those programmatically to identify the language, and then define the style changes within CSS

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click","div.selectLang select",function(){
   var curr=$("div.selectLang select").val();
    var arr=[".left",".left>p"];//list of elements to change fontsize
    if(curr=="English"){
    for(var i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
          var fontSize = parseInt($(arr[i]).css("font-size"));
       fontSize = fontSize - 3 + "px";
       $(arr[i]).css({'font-size':fontSize});
       }
    } else if(curr=="Spanish"){
  for(var i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
          var fontSize = parseInt($(arr[i]).css("font-size"));
       fontSize = fontSize + 3 + "px";
       $(arr[i]).css({'font-size':fontSize});
       }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.left {
    font-size: 16px;
}
.left>p {
    font-size: 20px;
}
.right {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="selectLang">
    <select>
    <option value="English" selected>English</option>
    <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
  </select>
  </div>

  <div class="left">
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
  <p>
  Where does it come from?
  </p>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look lik
  </div>
```